# Emacs helm-projectile-grep and Tramp mode

Tags: emacs, tramp, projectile, emacs-helm

When I try to use `helm-projectile-grep` while using `Tramp` mode in Emacs and then jump into a selected file, a path to this file is wrongly prepended with `/ssh:username@host-address:`. So, as a result a new file is created with the address `/ssh:username@host-address:/ssh:username@host-address:/home/username/file`. Notice, that `/ssh:username@host-address:` is repeated twice. Appreciate any information about overcoming the issue.

Comment: I use `projectile-ag` over tramp all the time, but I don't see this problem with either that or `projectile-grep`.  Try to reproduce it with a minimal config.  Does the built in `rgrep` (which `projectile-grep` uses) also have this problem?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Indeed `projectile-grep` works just fine. The issue is in `helm-projectile-grep`. Updated the question.